# DXL open a module

Tags: ibm-doors

Basically I would need a script(or function) that would look after a module (using it's name as a parameter),within a database and not projects, and return the module as it is for further operations on it.

I am using DOORS 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
Item i
Folder f = folder("/")
Folder f2

void drill_items(Folder f) {
  for i in f do {
    if(type(i) "" == "Formal")
        \\ Do some logic here to check if its the module you are looking for.
        \\ If you find it, break out and return the Module handle.
    else if((type(i) "" == "Project") || (type(i) "" == "Folder")) {
        f2 = folder(fullName(i) "")
        drill_items(f2)
    }
  }
}

drill_items(f)
```

You could write something using a regular expression to compare some input to the module name to find the one you are looking for.

-Steve